# TypeScript - infer function's argument type based on return type from another function

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
interface Res<R = any> {
    first?(): Promise<R>;
    second(arg: { response: R }): void;
}
```

When I create a plain object based on the above interface, the response type is not properly infered as shown in the example below:

```
const entity: Res = {
    first: () => Promise.resolve({ name: 'Bob' }),
    second: (arg) => {
        console.log(arg.response) // is "any", but should be "{ name: string }"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get a proper type for `arg.response` based on what the `first()` method has returned?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4B5XILzJwgCeAfMgN4BQytyMwUGYA-ABQCUAXMgApQB7ALbAMEHKQDcNOmIQCQAEzZwoAcx4VkUTAAcFYnrgC%203ZADcBwRdONUq8kM2QRwwMMSOZ8lGbQZMYDyc%20OT8wqIQAHQ6GAIANuYQbFogcEIQPADkAEICAEZZyKYANH7IcgqKwapqHKG%20dE3IjnHx0fECairqMXoGEPUA9EPIosgARETEEyXI%20QCuYBUAFgIL8YrzKBOp6ZkVYFCgasUT5XZ2VEA)

Comment: Isn't it because of the any that is defined in the interface' result? If you create a model for the result, which contains a name property, it will show you the proper type.

Comment: Yes, that's because of it, but the point is that I don't want to write a model for the result because it can be infered: `first: () => Promise.resolve({ name: 'Bob' })` - this function returns a model `{ name: string }`.

Comment: You never specify the generic argument when declaring `const entity: Res`, so it naturally uses `R = any` (the default). Inferring the argument in this case is not possible - you've *not* specified any generic, so it should also be usable with `Res<number>` for example.

Comment: Yup, @feerlay you will probably have to go along the lines of this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4B5XILzIAK0GA9iAHzIDeAUMg8jMFBmAPwAUAlAFxFRSAW2AYIOCgG56jMQnIATTnCgBzftWRRMAB3Jj+uAL59kAN1LAF0o7VryQbZBHDAwAT0OZ8NGQ2asYPw8+FSEgiJiAHTaZAA2ZhCcmiBwQhD8AOQAQqQARpnIJgA0fshyisEqqtyhvowNyA7xEFFxpKrKajG6+hC1APQDyKLIAERwIO5jxch5AK5g5QAWpPNxCnMoYylpGeVgUKCqRWNltrb2cXAYGEQk5PWMqen8bEcgqtJlTfqH8wgwKQoCE6I1GGBlqIoi8UAQxqh8mNpA0LrQgA

Comment: @Devilscomrade no need for an entire class `const entity: Res<{name: string}>` can be enough. Or creating an interface. A class is probably an overkill.

Comment: Alright, if there is no way in TS to infer the type, then I will get rid of `= any` and make it required to pass a generic type. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with just a variable, you can use the inference behavior of functions to get the desired behavior:

```
interface Res<R = any> {
    first?(): Promise<R>;
    second(arg: { response: R }): void;
}

function createRes<T>(o: Res<T>) {
    return o
}
const entity = createRes({
    first: () => Promise.resolve({ name: 'Bob' }),
    second: (arg) => {
        console.log(arg.response)
    }
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4B5XILzJwgCeAfMgN4BQytyMwUGYA-ABQCUAXMgApQB7ALbAMEHKQDcNOmIQCQAEzZwoAcx4VkUTAAcFYnrgC+3ZADcBwRdONUqMAK4gEYYAuQIdcSOmwAVUjYBI0wsQI5KGVodMEcoEGQBKjt5EGZkCHBgMGJ8T29fTDZqOnpGZh5OfHJ+YVEIADodDAEAG3MIEuQQOCEIHgByACEBACNB5FMAGmjkOQVFKtU1SLxyUrK6NNa2praBNRV1Zr0DCA45u1N7IA)

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks cool! One question tho: why does it break when I add an argument to the `first` method and use it: `first?(age: string): Promise<R>` and `first: (age) => Promise.resolve({ name: 'Bob' })`?